# Converting ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> to ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been trying to convert string of `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> to ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`

Here is my codes that I tried to build.

```
public void convertString (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> templist) {
    readList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ();
    for (ArrayList<String> t : templist) {
        readList.add(Integer.parseInt(t));
    }
    return readList;
```

Need some advice on how to convert it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, keep in mind when converting a String to an Integer

"you'll notice the "catch" is that this function can throw a NumberFormatException"
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5585800/4977223

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this using Stream API:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = ...

List<List<Integer>> result = list.stream()
    .map(l -> l.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Or if you really need `ArrayList` and not `List`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = ...

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = list.stream()
  .map(l -> l.stream().map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)))
  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Assuming you are using Java 8 or later.

Comment: Java 8 is long dead. If someone wants a historical answer, it's reasonable to mention the older version of Java in the question itself

Comment: My information may be out-of-date but I thought Android was stuck on Java 6,

Answer (score 3):

You have nested lists so you will need a nested for-loop.

```java
for (ArrayList<String> t: tempList) {
    ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s: t) {
        a.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }
    readList.add(a);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java-8 you can use :

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> convertString(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> templist) {
    return templist.stream()
            .map(l -> l.stream()
                    .map(Integer::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)))
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

I would suggest to use `List` instead of `ArrayList` :

```
public List<List<Integer>> convertString(List<List<String>> templist) {
    return templist.stream()
            .map(l -> l.stream()
                    .map(Integer::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With java-8, you do it as below,

```
templist.stream()
        .map(l->l.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This would be `List<List<Integer>`. If you want `ArrayList` you can use,

```
Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new)
```

Comment: Not quite: this gives you a `List<List<Integer>>`.